# MS Exchange 2019 Install Error - Active Directory Operation Failed on dc.domain - Directory Object Not Found

Tags: exchange-server

Completely new install of MS Exchange 2019, installed all the prerequisites for the Mailbox role successfully and schema created across the 4 domain controllers in the environment.

Had to manually create the schema on the root domain as the Exchange server was on the child domain, however schema replicated successfully across the domains in the environment.

During the installation on the Exchange server, the installation stages will always stop at stage 8/12 (Installation of Mailbox role). Checked the logs and it returns the following error messages:

```
***[ERROR] Active Directory operation failed on dc.domain. The error is not retriable. Additional information: Directory object not found.
Active Directory response: 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100288, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of: 'DC= dc, Dc= dc, Dc= dc'
[ERROR] The object does not exist
[ERROR-REFERENCE] Id=MailboxServiceControlLast_05b3bbd421504e0c93fefa6d5d1ae590
Component=EXCHANGE14:\Current\Release\Shared\Datacenter\Setup
Setup is stopping now because of one or more critical errors
Finished executing components tasks
Ending process Install-MailboxRole***
```

P.S In the right security groups to execute the installation (Schema and Enterprise Admins).

Any help or advice will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the `Users` Container `CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com` or the Object in question from Type Container to an Organizational Unit? The setup expects some Objects as Container. `Users` is one of them.